# Set width of LinearLayout declared in XML Programatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-spinner

I am trying to set the width of my LinearLayout code side.  I am trying to find a way that I can size my selectedNavigationItem of my IcsSpinner to the selected item size...when I set the linearLayout in xml to a certain width, this is achieved...but I need dynamic sizing.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinner_ll"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="right" >

        <com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Is there any way to set the width of the LinearLayout, not the child?

UPDATE...ANSWER:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)ll.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = 85;  // set this to size...this is arbitrary number for proof of concept
ll.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the layout parameters from code like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.spinner_11);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100 /* in pixels */, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

You can convert dps to pixels in code like this:

```
int pixelValue = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10 /* in dps */, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Take a look at the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension(int, float, android.util.DisplayMetrics)

Comment: This is almost correct for my situation .... I needed to preserve the other layout params in my xml.  Therefore I need to do this:  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)ll.getLayoutParams();
  lp.width = 85;
  ll.requestLayout();

Comment: Sure, you can do that too, I was just keeping it simple :)